# Profiling and debugging techniques for high uptime ADK controlling application?

Tags: android, android-service, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adk, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've recently ported an application that is known to run with uptime of months ([DIY Zoning Project](http://diy-zoning.sourceforge.net/)) to Android (the [accessory driver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sf.dz4.adk), the [core process](http://www.homeclimatecontrol.com/overseer) and the [remote control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeclimatecontrol.dz3.view.android)). And, unfortunately, though techniques to keep running services alive were used (START_STICKY, startForeground()), sometimes the system^H service app just freezes up - until the user initiates an interaction with the service, after which it resumes normal operation. Most problematic is the fact that it is happening intermittently, and mostly after several days of uptime. The remote control works on the emulator for days at a time with no noticeable degradation, so the problem is most probably either in the service or in the accessory driver.

Currently, the system is targeted at API 10, so advanced service scheduling features are not available - that is, if they're related to the problem to begin with.

Now, what is the realistic way to debug and/or profile such a system? Remember, adb is not available for the Android hardware is connected to an ADK accessory.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a late answer, however, did you try to use Wakelocks? 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html
Possibly the system just hibernates the processor in some cases and it seems like "freezing up"

Comment: I used the word "system" ambiguously - it's not the whole Android OS that is freezing, that's the background app (the service).